# Wondering how Facebook does the "Mutual friends" feature

Tags: database, database-design, facebook

I'm currently developing an application to allow students to manage their courses, and I don't really know how to design the database for a specific feature.
The client wants, a lot like Facebook, that when a student displays the list of people currently in a specific course, the people with the most mutual courses with the logged in user are displayed first. Almost the same as Facebook feature "Friend suggestions" with an additional filter.

As an additional feature, I would like to add a search feature to allow students to search for another one, and displaying first in the search results the people with most mutual courses with the logged in user.

I currently use MySQL, I plan to use Cassandra for some other features, and I also use Memcached for result caching and Sphinx for the search.

Thanks.

--

The app is developed in Python, BTW

And I forgot to mention that the standard approach (using a nice MySQL query to calculate all this with an ORDER BY clause) is wayyyys too slow. So as reads are a lot more frequent than reads, I would like most of the logic to take place once, when the relation people <-> course is added.

I thought about updating a "mutual courses" counter specific to one tuple (user, course) that will be increased for all users of a course when the logged in user joins a new course (or decreased when he leaves it).

Comment: What do you mean people with the most mutual friends? You mean find another user who has as many of the same friends as the person who is currently logged in? you will also need to say what language you are developing in. It looks like web based stuff, but mySQL can be used for standalone applications. And we still need to know if it's PHP/ASP/JS or some other language.

Comment: Yep, you understood me right.
The application is developed in Python, but really, I would be facing the same exact problem with any other language. I don't expect people to help me with code, but with structural ideas :)

Comment: Implementing "mutual friends" would be somewhat different from implementing a "most mutual courses" feature. The former needs only one type of entity (person), and a relationship "is friend with". The latter had two entities (student, course) and relationship between student and course from which relationships between students would need to be extrapolated.

Comment: Yes, I see it will be different. But the logic behind the cover will probably have a lot in common. How did they manage to have that much performance with hundreds of millions users and probably billions of relationships between them.

Comment: I have read in a few places that say it may be better to pull data from SQL unsorted, and the compare table results in your code. I can see the logic if you only have a small amount of CPU for the DB and a large amount for your web server.

Comment: That's what I would do. But here, I'm talking about a huge (really) database, and getting 10.000 entries to display only 10 is a fantastic waste of memory and CPU. And if I just fetch 10, the database will still do the job. The ideal would be in fact to have the data already ordered in the database. Like with Cassandra.

Comment: Are you sure you can't speed up the database with some carefully chosen indexes? This kind of stuff should be easy for any database server, even with 100,000 students.

Comment: There is indexes, and they are used for the join clause, if I trust the EXPLAIN command.
The problem is that this solution is not really scalable. Today, it may be viable with 100.000 people. But tomorrow, with a couple of million users?

Comment: Would you let us know how you finally did that and preferably a link to your application? Thanks.

Comment: Hey. I can't link to my application mainly because it's internal. But I finally used ElasticSearch for that purpose : when a student joins or leaves a course, I store in ElasticSearch the list of every course for that user. When looking for mutual friends, I just run a query on users, passing as parameter that list, and ordering it by score, all simply. Given the pretty low number of courses and per user, it runs fast, and can be cached. It also gives me a feature-rich search engine at the same time. We're happy with that solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have your solution, but the problem is just the speed of that query, try doing it sooner. When a user's friendships change, rerun a job that calculates these things and store all the results away. Don't runt his as a result of a request, when you need the result so quickly. Do such expensive things only once and do them before a request is ever made.

Comment: So, when a new relationship is added, do what I thought about: update a counter for mutual relationships (in Cassandra) for each user already in the course.
When displaying the results, just take the data from Cassandra, display the results as they come (already ordered), and display other users (with no relationships) after... -- My only concern would still be performance. Wouldn't it be a huge overhead when joining a course with thousands of people in it?

Comment: Depends on if you do "for x in y: updatesql(newvalue)" or "UPDATE counter = counter + 1 where ...". The first is going to hit network overhead. The second should be pretty fast.

Comment: Yep. If done in SQL, I totally agree with you. But the performance problem is still (a little) alive. If I talk about a course with 100.000 people in it (yes, there is!), wouldn't the query `SELECT u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN relationships r ON (u.id == r.user_id_1 OR u.id == r.user_id_2) ORDER BY r.mutual_counter LIMIT ...` be a little expensive? If I use Cassandra, I can store already ordered data. But as far as I know, I have to loop through the relationships manually :/

Comment: Or maybe (not decreasing the time necessary, but improving the user experience) by delegating this work to other servers, for example with Gearman?

Answer (score 5):

Say you have a table that is named `Users` and the Primary Key is `UserID`. Then you have a table called `Friends` with 2 columns called `UserID` (PK) and `FriendUserID`.

Say you have 2 users, 20 and 50.

When 20 adds 50 as friend, the application adds a new row:

```
INSERT INTO `Friends` (`UserID`, `FriendUserID`) VALUES (20, 50)
```

and when 50 confirms friendship, you add another row with values switched:

```
INSERT INTO `Friends` (`UserID`, `FriendUserID`) VALUES (50, 20)
```

When you want to find mutual friends between 20 and 50, simply:

```
SELECT `UserID` FROM `Friends` AS `A`, `Friends` AS B WHERE `A`.`FriendUserID` = 20 AND `A`.`UserID` = `B`.`UserID` AND `B`.`FriendUserID` = 50
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks. That works.
But that's definitely not a viable solution, for performance issues. Even if that request is made when a new relation takes place to calculate and store the results, this would be ways too slow with a pretty big table.

Comment: This looks good, but why dont you find the mutual friends and store them in another table so that you dont have to do the calculations again and again, instead just run a job that would update the mutual friends whenever the user makes a new connection

Answer (score 0):

I would break this up as (2) queries and find the intersection in Python:

```
#Query 1 - Get the user's friends
SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 'my user id'

#Query 2 - Get the users enrolled in the course
SELECT student_id FROM course_enrollment WHERE course_id = 'course id'
```

Then find the intersection in Python.
Then you can let the database do caching, etc ... without any joins to slow things down.