# How does facebook calculate mutual friends?

Tags: php, mysql, graph, database-design, web-development-server

In your opinion, how does facebook calculate mutual friends?

Has it cached all mutual friends for each user?
Or does it let MySQL calculate through a query each time it displays them?
Or does it make a query to the database and then calculate from a list?
Or is there another way?

Comment: They dont tell us stuff like this... But your MySQL calculation seems more likely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wondering how Facebook does the "Mutual friends" feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536891/wondering-how-facebook-does-the-mutual-friends-feature)

Comment: Maybe this question is more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: they're really doing computer science there. for any person you haven't visited before you can immediately see mutual friends. most probably they have a graph structure. but how they implement is really a serious topic and I bet many people continuously working on such algorithms of facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is pre-computed and not done when you load the page. 
How? There are a couple of options to look at this problem. 
A common way is to look at the data as a graph, where each person is a vertex, and an edge defines a friendship. Iterating through each existing pair of persons, and finding 2 edges paths. The vertexes you went over, are the mutual friends. If you really want to get into it, I would suggest starting with learning about [Graph Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)

When dealing with such an amount of data, using MySql and queries won't work. On small amounts of data, it will.